# Assign a static IP address to an AWS Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have a load balancer created in my VPC with two subnets. Now I want to open a firewall rule from within my company intranet. I have no control over this firewall. But to open a rule on the firewall - the firewall team is accepting only ip addresses and not the DNS names.

But since the IP address of the load balancer keeps changing I can't give it to the firewall team. That's where I am stuck.

How can I open a firewall rule to an AWS load balancer from within my intranet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that an **Application Load Balancer** does *not* provide static IP addresses.

You might be able to change to a [**Network Load Balancer**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html):

> Elastic Load Balancing creates a network interface for each Availability Zone you enable. Each load balancer node in the Availability Zone uses this network interface to get a **static IP address**. When you create an Internet-facing load balancer, you can optionally associate **one Elastic IP address per subnet**.

It is also possible to put a Network Load Balancer *in front of* an **Application Load Balancer** to gain the benefits of both.

See: [Using static IP addresses for Application Load Balancers | AWS Networking & Content Delivery Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/)

Comment: thanks John. But this isnt an optimal solution for my case. Adds couple of layers which needs to be maintained. And this really looks like a hack instead of a proper solution !

Comment: You might be able to _only_ use a Network Load Balancer (instead of an Application Load Balancer). If so, it would be a very clean solution.